# I'm unable to plot csv data using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, import-csv

I have created a csv data like:[csv image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yK8c.png)
link to csv data: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiBcPojQRu1SgRw-uiiRIQ0LhXYi?e=uEU9d5

and when I print the csv data it shows like this : [printed using pandas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9H9jX.png)
[code I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JCRg.png)

and when I plot the data using matplotlib it shows: [error on plotting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhfNd.png)
can anyone help me with this?

Comment: pls show the code plot chart that have error?

Comment: @bao.le I've attached the image to the post now

Comment: I'm a little confused as to why you call that CSV; in my browser it looks like a spreadsheet, and when I go to "save as" and choose "download a copy", the server tries to send me an .xlsx file?

Comment: Also, you should add the code as text into the body of your question; the `{}` icon can be used to format it as code.

Comment: yah I convert the xlsx to csv using a online converter. Ill use the '{}' next time onwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Read csv file with header and here are also sub header so need both headers and delete unwanted **unmamed** which create onself instead of blank space.
and then possible to plotting.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#read csv file
covid  = pd.read_csv('D:/kerala.csv',header=[1,2],index_col=[0])
print(covid)

#use Header and Subheader
a = covid.columns.get_level_values(0).to_series()
b = a.mask(a.str.startswith('Unnamed')).ffill().fillna('')
covid.columns = [b, covid.columns.get_level_values(1)]
print (covid)

#plotting
covid.plot()
plt.show()
```

**HOPE IT HELP YOU**

Comment: It did worked but is it possible to the output like this?: https://prnt.sc/SPyJr_t9V4Xd

Comment: covid  = pd.read_csv('D:/kerala.csv',header=[1,2],index_col=[0]),,,,Just use this statement instead of previous it will work garph with district name.